# Sorting uploaded files, based on a list of ids

Tags: php, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

Good evening.
I added the JQuery UI sortable features to my upload page, that uses Blueimp JQuery File Uploader.
The order is stored in a json file, because I need it to show the images on my front-end in a specific sequence.

Now the question is: how can I show the thumbs on the back-end using the same order? Once I reload the page, all pictures get sorted alphabetically... this does not match the real ordering.

Comment: If the the order is stored on a json file, why cant you reference the json file on the back end and order it using the results?

Comment: I modifided the text of my question. It was not clear that I was talking about JQuery Uploader by Blueimp.
That's the point!